# Riemannian simplicial complex and quasi-conformal complex

Tags: reference-request, definitions

In [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1303.1162) by Robert Young, the author defines

> We define a riemannian simplicial complex to be a simplicial
>   complex with a metric which gives each simplex the structure of a riemannian
>   manifold with corners. 
>   We say that such a complex is quasi-conformal (or that the complex is a QC complex
>   ) if there is a $c$ such that the riemannian metric on each simplex is
>   $c$-bilipschitz equivalent to a scaling of the standard simplex.

I have some problem understanding the next paragraph:

> QC complexes are a compromise between the rigidity of simplicial
>   complexes and the freedom of riemannian simplicial complexes. A key
>   feature of simplicial complexes is that curves and cycles can be
>   approximated by simplicial curves and cycles. This is not true in
>   riemannian simplicial complexes, but it holds in QC complexes.

What confuses me is that in the definition of Riemannian simplicial complex one starts with a simplicial complex. But the paragraph below says that a Riemannian simplicial complex is not a simplicial complex.

Can anyone recommend additional references to both riemmanian simplicial complexes and QC complexes?

Comment: Robert is talking about the *metric* properties of these complexes; the rigidity he refers to comes from endowing each simplex with the metric coming from the standard simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @AndyPutman oh, that clears things up. thanks.

Comment: @AndyPutman so in short: simplical complex -> simplices have metric from standard simplex; riemannian simplicial complex -> simplices have riemannian metric that makes each simplex into a manifold; QC comples -> simplices have metric which is almost like that of standard simplex (up to some scaling)?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is correct.